# Plotting color codes in matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot

Say I am having the following matrix:

```
0    0.104    0.37
0.104   0    0.27
0.37    0.27    0
```

These are correlation values, and I want to create a matrix representing the values with colors in MATLAB.
I know of this function:

imagesc(corrData)

I want to however have 1. colors from a similar color scale (say all blue, from light to dark blue)
2. A bar which maps the values to the colors
How can I do that in Matlab?

This is an example of what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Something like [`this`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html?s_tid=doc_ta#bux1nvc-1)?

Comment: Yes, that is useful for the colorbar! However, how do I change the colorrange, and also get rid off the axis numeration?

Comment: Throughout the example I linked, it talks about "colormap". You might want to look that up. Please read [ask]. The first suggestion there is to "Search and Research" before asking.

Comment: Thanks for the condescencing comment, but I read what colormap means, and it is a mapping from the values within this already given colorscale, when you for instance only want to map a certain subset of the values in the matrix..so it's not at all what I am asking for, and I am not sure if MATLAB imagesc function does provide what I want (I have obviously already known this function, see my original question)

Comment: Then you've done more then you're presenting here, and we have no way to know where your confusion lies. If you post the code that you've tried, and clarify how it fails to meet your requirements, then perhaps we can give more pertinent suggestions. For example, your first point "colors from a similar color scale (say all blue, from light to dark blue)" seems to be covered [`here`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html#budglf4-1), but since we can't see what you've tried, we can't tell you how to fix it.

Comment: The [documentation for `colorbar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorbar.html) provides [all of the properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.illustration.colorbar-properties.html) of the object. Including [`'TickLabels'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.illustration.colorbar-properties.html#property_d119e131053) and the [`'Limits'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.illustration.colorbar-properties.html#property_d119e132433). These should be sufficient for what you need to adjust.